# How to use firebase admob on ionic 2

Tags: firebase, ionic2

Want to integrate my ionic 2 app with the firebase admob. It has a well documentation for native android mobile app and IOS but not for the hybrid apps. Tried the cordova plugin but out of luck.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow SO guidelines:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask